# retrieve value of arraylist in javascript in same page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, arraylist

There is a JSP page in which i have an ArrayList variable. I need these arraylist values(txt1 and txt2) in script tag.I have tried lots of combinations and googling but didnot succeed.

javascript function

```
function fun1()
{   
   // how to get arraylist values      
}
```

JSP page:

```
 <body>
       <%
           ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
           al.add("txt1");
           al.add("txt2");

           out.println("<input type=text id=" + al.get(0) + ">");out.println("<br>");
           out.println("<input type=text id= " + al.get(1) + ">");out.println("<br>");
           out.println("<input type=button id=btn1  value=click onClick=fun1(); > ");
       %>
 </body>
```

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside javascript you can  use Scriplets very well

Assume the list 'arrayList' is having [1,2,3,4] in java (JSP)

you can get the array list by this

```
function fun1()
{   
   var list = '<%= arrayList %>';
}
```

if you print the variable **list**, it will be a string with value '[1,2,3,4]'

You can then split this using Regex or simple string operation

```
<body>
       <%
           ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
           al.add("txt1");
           al.add("txt2");

           out.println("<input type=text id=" + al.get(0) + ">");out.println("<br>");
           out.println("<input type=text id= " + al.get(1) + ">");out.println("<br>");
           out.println("<input type=button id=btn1  value=click onClick=fun1(); > ");
       %>
 </body>

<script>
 // try the script here
</script>
```

Comment: I tried var list='<%= al %>' , but it gives error saying " al can not be resolved"

Comment: Your jsp code must be above the javascript for the scope to work.
Put your JSP Code first and then the javscript code.

Comment: Because scope of array list is local. use scriptlets <%! declarations %> instead of <% declarations %>.

Comment: Dude.. he he.. there is an option called Accept . Please click that. So that , people who see the same problem in future, can direct take the answer instead trying out all the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<script>
var myArray=new Array();
myArray[0] = '<%= al.get(0) %>';
myArray[1] = '<%= al.get(1) %>';
<script>
```

Comment: Try to print out the data of al before you use this code to make sure it has values.

Comment: yaah. al contains values "txt1,txt2"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script tag which creates an array in js that holds all you values. I'm not familar with jsp but deppending on oyur code it could look like:

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
out.println("var myJsArray = new Array();");
foreach(var arrayMember in al)
{
    out.println("myJsArray.push(" + arrayMember + ");");
}
out.println("</script>");
```

In Js just use the array:

```
function fun1()
{
    var firstArrayMember = myJsArray[0];
    // or whatever you want to do
}
```

You could also use assoziativ arrays if you have a key for a specific array member.

Hope you got the idea

Comment: Why print code to build the array, when you can just print the array literal?

Comment: As i started to write this answer there was not an other one... As I said I'm not familiar with JSP, just wanted to give him an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the Java code somewhere else, but if you insist on having it inside your JSP, try having readable HTML and only output Java content using `<%=...%>` - something like this:

```
<%
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("text1");
  list.add("text2");
%>

<body>

  <form ...>
    <input type="text" id="<%=list.get(0)%>" />
    <input type="text" id="<%=list.get(1)%>" />
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Click" onclick="functionOne();" />
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function functionOne() {
      alert(document.getElementById("<%=list.get(0)%>").value);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```